# Origin of the phrase “in alter Frische”

Tags: etymology, phrase

This week, I have seen a shop sign<sup>1</sup> that basically ran as:

> Am Montag, den 4. Mai 2020 sind wir in alter Frische wieder für Sie
> da.

I understand that “*in alter Frische*“ could mean “fully operational”, “fresh as ever” etc and would like to know how this interesting phrase came into being.

**EDIT**:
Also found this text on Google Images, which seems to appear in many humorous formats.

[image]

Source: (1) Paraphrased from [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=in%20alter%20Frische)

Comment: Interestingly, the Website https://www.redensarten-index.de does in this case not suggest an origin but resorts to a lazy "colloquial expression" pseudo explanation. So I would be curious too, if something like a source or a place of first occurrence can be found.

Comment: I found it used in a letter from Erich Schmidt and Theodor Storm January 1883 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=EqVcEAEi8h4C&pg=PA71&dq=%22alter+frische%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjByYXox_boAhWozYUKHTxaDtIQ6AEIbTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22alter%20frische%22&f=false).

Comment: Further match in Jenaer Allgemeine Literatur-Zeitung from 1836 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=G89aAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22alter%20frische%22&hl=de&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q=%22alter%20frische%22&f=false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of the phrase is not idiomatic, i.e. it is semantically transparent: *Frische* means *vigour* and *alt* means *former*. Phrases of this kind can be formed *ad hoc*; they have no special genesis.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/alt#d-1-6 paraphrases *alt* with *früher, vorherig* and gives the example:

> etw. befindet sich am alten Fleck, Platz

https://www.dwds.de/wb/Frische#d-1-1 paraphrases *Frische* as *Lebhaftigkeit, volle körperliche und geistige Kraft*.

Comment: Hm... yes and no. You are right that theoretically everybody can create this up ad hoc. But... would he? Still *in alter Frische* has an oxymoronic hue to it which makes it seem purposefully created, not accidentally. A less poetic and more everyday way to combine "vigour" and "former" would be: *frisch wie am Morgen* or something like that.

Comment: it is fully idiomatic, as *alt* and *frisch* are basicly antonyms, to the point that I'm tempted to compare Lat. *ult[ima]*, PIE \*h2el- "to grow" to suggest  *reif* "ripe" (short of *mature*) ... but have nothing to show for it (i.e. no comparative evidence I'm aware)

Comment: @David Vogt:  Thanks for the update, now this makes perfect sense.

Comment: I am not convinced that in this context "alt" means something  like "old" or "previous". In the first link to dwds we find completely different interpretions under 7., but I think also  these do not fit here. In my opinion it should be understood als "in gewohnter Frische" or "in bekannter Frische".

Comment: @PaulFrost *Der alte Platz* could definitely imply *der bekannte Platz*.

Comment: @DavidVogt I agree. What do you think about "in alter Frische = in  voller körperlicher und geistiger Kraft"?

Comment: @DavidVogt By the way, your answer explains the meaning of the phrase, but does not really explain its origin. Perhaps you are right that "Phrases of this kind can be formed ad hoc; they have no special genesis", but this does not say much more than "nobody knows".

Comment: @PaulFrost If it is unidiomatic, it has no origin – only a first occurrence.